# MySQL Huge DELETE

Tags: performance, mysql-5.7, query-performance

I'm trying to delete 10000 rows from my database on MySQL 5.7 but it's been stuck for 7 hours.

**Query:**

```
DELETE FROM article WHERE id in (52109548,52109558,52109560,52109564,....).
```

This are my buffer settings:

```
mysql> show variables like "%buffer%";
+-------------------------------------+----------------+
| Variable_name                       | Value          |
+-------------------------------------+----------------+
| bulk_insert_buffer_size             | 67108864       |
| innodb_buffer_pool_chunk_size       | 134217728      |
| innodb_buffer_pool_dump_at_shutdown | ON             |
| innodb_buffer_pool_dump_now         | OFF            |
| innodb_buffer_pool_dump_pct         | 25             |
| innodb_buffer_pool_filename         | ib_buffer_pool |
| innodb_buffer_pool_instances        | 32             |
| innodb_buffer_pool_load_abort       | OFF            |
| innodb_buffer_pool_load_at_startup  | ON             |
| innodb_buffer_pool_load_now         | OFF            |
| innodb_buffer_pool_size             | 34359738368    |
| innodb_change_buffer_max_size       | 25             |
| innodb_change_buffering             | all            |
| innodb_log_buffer_size              | 16777216       |
| innodb_sort_buffer_size             | 1048576        |
| join_buffer_size                    | 8388608        |
| key_buffer_size                     | 8388608        |
| myisam_sort_buffer_size             | 134217728      |
| net_buffer_length                   | 16384          |
| preload_buffer_size                 | 32768          |
| read_buffer_size                    | 2097152        |
| read_rnd_buffer_size                | 262144         |
| sort_buffer_size                    | 262144         |
| sql_buffer_result                   | OFF            |
```

This is my show create table:

```
CREATE TABLE `article` (
 `id` int(255) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `iptc_id` int(255) NOT NULL,
 `title_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `article_original_data_id` int(255) NOT NULL,
 `language_id` int(255) NOT NULL,
 `headline` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
 `summary` text,
 `body` longtext,
 `author` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
 `date` date DEFAULT NULL,
 `parsed_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
 `updated_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
 `has_time` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
 `is_Calias_called` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `sub_feed` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 KEY `article_FKIndex11` (`language_id`),
 KEY `article_FKIndex21` (`article_original_data_id`),
 KEY `article_FKIndex31` (`iptc_id`),
 KEY `article_FKIndex41` (`title_id`),
 KEY `parsed_at1` (`parsed_at`),
 KEY `date1` (`date`),
 KEY `index_calias1` (`is_Calias_called`),
 CONSTRAINT `article_ibfk_11` FOREIGN KEY (`language_id`) REFERENCES `language` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
 CONSTRAINT `article_ibfk_21` FOREIGN KEY (`article_original_data_id`) REFERENCES `article_original_data` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
 CONSTRAINT `article_ibfk_31` FOREIGN KEY (`iptc_id`) REFERENCES `iptc` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
 CONSTRAINT `article_ibfk_41` FOREIGN KEY (`title_id`) REFERENCES `title` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=102032641 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Comment: Yes, its my pk PRIMARY KEY (`id`)

Comment: This is my slave server and when the slave tried to delete 1000 records its get stuck and now seconds behind master more than 10000 seconds as its waiting to complete the delete sql, On master the query was pretty fast . my master Server is 5.5 and slave 5.7 , I was thinking about how come mysql delete on 5.5 faster than 5.7 ...

Comment: I don't know - that seems  like a fairly big regression to have been missed in testing? But, you never know, maybe there's something about your setup that's outside the usual range of tested conditions? Can you switch back to 5.5 for your slave and see if it works then? Can you even run a sample test on a machine - just the delete on 5.5 without setting up your whole configuration? Again, where's `SHOW CREATE TABLE article\G` (no semi-colon)? Hmm... almost 3 hours behind! You'll have to explore and test I'm afraid - I assume that your `SHOW VARIABLES` settings are the same? For everything?

Comment: Thank you, I edit the question to add show create table. My database size around 200GB and restoring will take more than 2 days. any faster solution or investigation?

Comment: when you tried to remove those rows, any chances you checked server performance? and table status if there something not normal with the table when you were trying to remove those lines `show table status <tablename>;`

Comment: After 10 hours seconds behind master becomes to 0 finally :). Now I reduced the number of bulk moving/deletion from 10,000 rows/bulk to 1000 and its working fine. For some reason MYSQL 5.7 not working properly with big rows deletion.

Comment: I deleted around 70 million records in less than an hour, using a procedure which will delete record in smaller chunks, I hope this helps you as well http://www.rathishkumar.in/2017/12/deleting-huge-number-of-records-in-mysql.html

Answer (score 0):

- As mention in the comment, the performance of the delete statement may be altered (and failed) if there are foreign key constraints to the affected table
- the key_buffer_size value is the default, you may want to increase this value, as suggested [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/delete-optimization.html)
- It seems that you have different key values on the delete statement, have you tried to execute them one by one?

Comment: I did this query on the master server mysql 5.5 and now the replication trying to execute it but its make seconds behind more than 9000. So I can't stop it. any chance to modify the global variables?

Comment: Also, key_buffer_size used for  MyISAM tables and my table is InnoDB